# como hacer para JSON solo reemplace datos de una columna con PHP?

Tags: php, json, datatables

buen dia
el problema que tengo es que en mi datatable quiero que muestre ciertos datos con un estilo  A UN COLUMNA EN ESPECIFICA, por ejemplo con $ para precios, o las fechas con su formato, etc.
solo que al hacer este codigo, solo reemplaza a lo que se igual al valor de la columna

```html
          if($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]==$aRow['totalCompra']){
     $row[]= "<td>$ ".number_format($aRow['totalCompra'])."</td>";
    }else
       $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i]];
```

todos los datos que se iguales los pone en ese formato. Por ejemplo en esta imagen se repiten $ en dos 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el codigo completo

```html
<?php
 /*
  * Script:    Tablas de multiples datos del lado del servidor para PHP y MySQL
  * Copyright: 2016 - Marko Robles
  * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
 */
///////////PRODUCTOS //////////////////
require_once( "class.php" );
$obj = new Trabajo(); //conexion
$idCarrito = 2; //ES 
$agregar=0;


 require '../php_conexion.php';
 
 /* Nombre de La Tabla */
 $sTabla = "compras";
 
 /* Array que contiene los nombres de las columnas de la tabla*/
 $aColumnas = array( 'idCompra','numeroCompra','idDistr','fechaCompra','formaPago', 'articulos' ,'totalCompra','statusCompra');
 
 /* columna indexada */
 $sIndexColumn = "idCompra";
 
 // Paginacion
 $sLimit = "";
 if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
 {
  $sLimit = "LIMIT ".$_GET['iDisplayStart'].", ".$_GET['iDisplayLength'];
 }
 
 
 //Ordenacion
 if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
 {
  $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
  {
   if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
   {
    $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
    ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
   }
  }
  
  $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
  if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
  {
   $sOrder = "";
  }
 }
 
 //Filtracion
 $sWhere = "";
 if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
 {
  $sWhere = "WHERE (";
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
  }
  $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
  $sWhere .= ')';
 }
 
 // Filtrado de columna individual 
 for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
 {
  if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
  {
   if ( $sWhere == "" )
   {
    $sWhere = "WHERE ";
   }
   else
   {
    $sWhere .= " AND ";
   }
   $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%' ";
  }
 }
 
 
 //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
 FROM   $sTabla
 $sWhere
 $sOrder
 $sLimit
 ";
 $rResult = $conexion->query($sQuery);
 
 /* Data set length after filtering */
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
 ";
 $rResultFilterTotal = $conexion->query($sQuery);
 $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
 $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
 
 /* Total data set length */
 $sQuery = "
 SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
 FROM   $sTabla
 ";
 $rResultTotal = $conexion->query($sQuery);
 $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
 $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
 
 /*
  * Output
 */
 $output = array(
 "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
 "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
 "aaData" => array()
 );
 


 while ( $aRow = $rResult->fetch_array())
 {
  $row = array();
  
  for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
  {
   
   if ( $aColumnas[$i] == "version" )
   {    
    /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
    $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ];
   }
   else if ( $aColumnas[$i] != ' ' )
   {
    /* General output */
    
    if($aRow[ $aColumnas[$i] ]==$aRow['totalCompra']){
     $row[]= "<td>$ ".number_format($aRow['totalCompra'])."</td>";
    }else
       $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i]];
      
    // }
    
    
        
   }
  }
  $row[]="<a href='compraDetalles.php?idc=".$aRow['numeroCompra']."'><button name='compraDetalles'  type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-primary'  value='Detalles'  >DETALLES<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></button></a>";
  $row[]="<a href='detalles_FACTURA.php?idc=".$aRow['numeroCompra']."'><button name='factura'  type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-primary'  value='factura'  >FACTURA<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></button></a>";
  
  $output['aaData'][] = $row;

 
  
 }

 echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas comparar los valores, es mejor que compares el nombre de la columna asi:

```
if($aColumnas[$i]=='totalCompra'){
  $row[]= "<td>$ ".number_format($aRow['totalCompra'])."</td>";
}else
  $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumnas[$i]];
}
```

Comment: listo, funciono a la primera, gracias